# Using sleep mode to trigger hybernate mode

Tags: windows-7, sleep, scheduled-tasks, hybrid-sleep

I wanted to set up my computer so that if i put it in sleep for more then 20 min, it will go into hibernate mode automatically. My hope was to use some sort of event trigger on window's Event Scheduler program. However, i am am really familiar with it and was hoping someone would know how to go about this.

Comment: Sleep [automatically transitions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) to hibernate when battery runs low. How do you expect Task Scheduler to work while the PC is sleeping?

Comment: By default, desktop computers automatically transition from sleep to hibernate -- see the info at Karan's link.

Comment: @Karan: The real-time clock in PCs can be scheduled to wake up from sleep at any given time. It's how earlier Windows versions (XP) used to go from sleep mode to hibernation.

Comment: @grawity: Yep, and isn't that a hardware option you'd typically set via the BIOS, and not via Task Scheduler? Also, are you implying that the same option can do what the OP requires, i.e. directly transition from sleep to hibernate on demand after X mins. have passed? I've personally never seen any BIOS offer such a feature, but perhaps you have?

Comment: @Karan: No, the RTC can also be programmed by the OS (e.g. using `rtcwake` on Linux). It is not BIOS-dependent, it works in any x86 system. And like I said, older operating systems such as WinXP used to work exactly as described – if you configured the OS to auto-suspend after 10 min and hibernate after 25 min, then just before suspending it would ask the RTC to wake the system 15 minutes later. When woken at that exact time, the OS would hibernate.

Comment: @grawity: Ok, so any way to get it to work in Vista+, same as on XP? I'm sure the OP would appreciate an informed answer from you (as would I). :)

Comment: @Karan: I'm not sure. Disabling hybrid sleep in power settings might do it... (I actually don't see what problems OP has with using hybrid sleep, to be honest.)